# Javascript Datepicker issue in browser

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I know that if we need to display the Date picker in HTML page we have to use Javascript. If the Javascript is disabled in the web browser how can i display the date picker. Can you help me to solve this problem..? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't do this without javasctipt :( Just like boiling egg without egg.

Comment: You cannot do this ! What do you think, how can you use javascript when it is disabled in the browser. And for your kind information : Many browsers in their latest versions have removed the option of enabling and disabling javascript !

Comment: Rahul, you are incorrect. Chrome and Firefox have the JS option among many in a very accesible and per site basis.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 input type=date; read more about it in the w3 website http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html or in several other high quality sources: [https://google.com/search?q=html5+input+date+-w3schools](https://google.com/search?q=html5%20input%20date%20-w3schools)